# Change pseudo-absolute assets path in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, actionview

I tried every way I found, but I don't know how to do it.

Rails always writes `/assets/...` and would like to have `./assets/` or `assets/` because my application is in a subfolder, not in the root folder.

I tried with `config.action_controller.asset_host = "."` but Rails writes `http://./assets/`

I tried with `config.assets.prefix = "."` but Rails writes `/./assets/`

Suppose that my application lives in: `http://domain.com/example/`, with the default behaviour of Rails every path points to `http://domain.com/` and not to `http://domain.com/example/`. I don't want to specify an absolute path, because that is not a portable solution.

Check this as an example: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to edit your environment file (`config/environments/development.rb`) under Rails 3, adding the line:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/example'
```

This line allows you to run in a subdirectory called "example." Note that you'll want to duplicate this change in `production.rb` and `test.rb` as well.